# Swift how to reuse my JSON HTTP Request header

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am making an application which makes a lot of requests from an API. So I don't want to copy and past the code over and over. I was wondering how I can reuse my code in a some more efficient way? Maybe with extensions? 
This is my code know:

```
func apiRequest() {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let username = "****"
    let password = "****"
    let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let userPasswordData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData?.base64EncodedString()
    let authString = "Basic " + (base64EncodedCredential)!
    print(authString)
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    var running = false
    let urlProjects = NSURL(string: "https://start.jamespro.nl/v4/api/json/projects/?limit=10")
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlProjects! as URL) {
        ( data, response, error) in
        if let taskHeader = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print(taskHeader.statusCode)
        }
        if error != nil {
            print("There is an error!!!")
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                    print(dictionary)

                    if let items = dictionary["items"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for item in items {
                            if let description = item["Description"] as? String {
                                self.projectNaam.append(description)
                            }
                            if let id = item["Id"] as? String {
                                self.projectId.append(id)
                            }
                            if let companyId = item["CompanyId"] as? String {
                                self.companyId.append(companyId)
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    self.apiRequestCompani()
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error: Could not get any data")
                }
            }
        }
        running = false
    }


    running = true
    task.resume()

    while running {
        print("waiting...")
        sleep(1)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Extensions to create a BaseViewController and extend that where you want to use your code over and over again. Then you should abstract all dynamic data over input parameters to that method.

```
import UIKit
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

func getApiRequest (Parameters) {
  //API Request
}
```

And then in your view controller you just extend BaseViewController

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Call method in baseviewcontroller
    getApiRequest(parameters)

    //Call method in self
    self.getApiRequest(parameters)
}

override func getApiRequest(Parameters) {

    //IF you need to override default configuration
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. Yes I get that but could you maybe give me an example of how to do that because I couldn't accomplish that. Thanks

Comment: @R.H i edit my answer. Couldn't check the code in own project, check if it works

Answer (score 0):

> So I don't want to copy and past the code over and over.

Absolutely right, no one aiming to get duplicated code; That's the issue of *massive view controller*. This issue appears since the view controller layer in your application handles most of the responsibilities, such as: getting data from the network, how data should be represented, deliver the formatted data to the view layer, etc...

There are many approaches for solving such an issue (using an appropriate architectural pattern for your application), for simplicity, I would recommend to apply the [*MVC-N*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html) (or MVCNetworking) approach into your app, it is almost the same usual MVC, with a separated files (managers), represent a new layer for handling -for instance- the integration with the external APIs.

Applying the MVN-N should not be that complex, nevertheless it needs to be described well (which might be too abroad to be descried in the answer), I would suggest to check the [above mentioned apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html), also watching [this video](https://news.realm.io/news/slug-marcus-zarra-exploring-mvcn-swift/) should be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I absolutely will check it out!